# Different JavaScript, JQuery or CSS for different Controller in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, codeigniter

I am working on Codeigniter v3 project, we are building an application for an organization and its a quite big in size. So that I want to load custom/different JQuery and CSS files/code for every Controller and its view in Codeigniter, so that I can minimize the load of every page.

Please help me how to achieve this in Codeigniter v3.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirement and project structure.

Normally you can implement it in different ways

1. Pass your different css/js file paths to associate view pages from the controller.
2. Put different static js/css file paths directly inside your each view pages.
3. You can create different Constants to define each css/js paths and can use in different views or pass those constants from controller to view.